# Transfer to Bank of America from Australia

Tags: united-states, money-transfer, australia, international-transfer, swift

I made an online transfer to Bank of America from Australia. The SWIFT code, routing number, name and address of the receiver are correct. However, I made a mistake in one digit of the account number. Will the receiver get the money?

Comment: Why not ask your bank?

Comment: The reason I always transfer a very small amount first, to make sure everything gets there. $1.23 is my  usual number. :-)

Comment: @PeterK. Fees for international wires easily run $15 for the receiver and $30 for the sender. So you got yourself a $45 test. Plus, there's no guarantee a teller won't type in the wrong number or misspell a name the second time.

Comment: @user71659 : OK. My experiments were with zero-fee providers, so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Will the receiver receive the account - yes - the receiver with the account number you've entered (if that account number actually exists) will receive it. Before you make any wire transfer, the bank (your bank in this case) asks you to confirm the details before hitting "submit" - which by hitting submit, you did.

If the receiving bank account does not exist due to an error in your typing, the money won't be deposited anywhere and the transaction will become void.

However, I would recommend (if you haven't already) that you call up your bank and put a stop on the transaction at the earliest (once you've realized the mistake).

Given the post is a week old, I'm sensing you've been able to resolve it. Nonetheless, my 2 cents on this.

Comment: The post is one year old.

Comment: Ha ! Thanks for pointing out Dheer. I didn't see 2017 

Answer (score 0):

> Australia the swift code routing number name and address of the receiver it's correct I made a mistake in one digit of the account number... Will the receiver get it?

This would depending on Bank in Australia; this would fall into repair. The Operations in Bank would determine if this are close enough and they make a credit, else they would raise a query with Bank in America or return the payment.